How to open AngularJS UI Bootstrap popover when a UI Grid cell is being edited
The following code snippet uses a directive named invalidnamesetter to raise the isInvalidName flag when the user types the word foo in a UI Grid cell.
As expected, the HTML <label> tag is set to isInvalidName = true when the word foo in a UI Grid cell, and set to isInvalidName = false otherwise.

However, the UI Bootstrap popover does not open when the isInvalidName flag is raised, although popover-is-open is set to {{grid.appScope.isInvalidName}} in the UI Grid cell template.

Questions:

Is this caused by a limitation of the Angular UI Grid or Bootstrap frameworks?
If not, what changes shall be done to that code snipped so that the UI Bootstrap popover opens when the user types the word foo in the UI Grid cell?



var mod = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

mod.directive('invalidnamesetter', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      colfield: '=',
      setinvalidnametotrue: '&',
      setinvalidnametofalse: '&'
    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.$watchGroup(['colfield'], function (values) {
        if(values[0] === 'foo') {
          scope.setinvalidnametotrue();
        } else {
          scope.setinvalidnametofalse();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

mod.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.setInvalidNameToTrue = function() {
    $scope.isInvalidName =true;
  }

  $scope.setInvalidNameToFalse = function() {
    $scope.isInvalidName =false;
  }

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name: ""}],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'Name',
        cellTemplate: '' +
          '<invalidnamesetter ' +
          '    colfield="COL_FIELD"' +
          '    setinvalidnametotrue="grid.appScope.setInvalidNameToTrue()"' +
          '    setinvalidnametofalse="grid.appScope.setInvalidNameToFalse()"' +
          '  <div' +
          '      uib-popover="foo is not allowed" ' +
          '      popover-append-to-body = "true" ' +
          '      popover-trigger="\'none\'" ' +
          '      popover-is-open="{{grid.appScope.isInvalidName}}" ' +
          '      class="form-control">' +
          '    {{COL_FIELD}}' +
          '  </div>' +
          '</invalidnamesetter>'
      }
    ]
  };
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>       

  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>isInvalidName = {{isInvalidName}}</label>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>




The directive is not needed actually, you can directly add the condition to popover-enable and set the trigger to mouseover, then without any logic, the popover will show/hide based on the value of COL_FIELD.
Working example below.


var mod = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

mod.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name: ""}],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'Name',
        cellTemplate: '' +
          '  <div' +
          '      uib-popover="foo is not allowed" ' +
          '      popover-append-to-body = "true" ' +
          '      popover-trigger="\'mouseover\'"   popover-enable="COL_FIELD == \'foo\'" ' +
          '      class="form-control">' +
          '    {{COL_FIELD}}' +
          '  </div>'
      }
    ]
  };
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>       

  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>isInvalidName = {{isInvalidName}}</label>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>




Thanks for your reply.
Setting the popover-trigger to mouseover instead of none requires the edition of the UI grid cell to be completed so that the popover is displayed when the cursor is moved over the UI grid cell.
Unfortunately, I cannot mark your answer as accepted since the popover needs to be displayed DURING the edition of the cell, as soon as the word foo is typed in the UI grid cell.
Background: The purpose is to provide a live feedback to the user while she is typing text in the UI grid cell.

Here is my suggestion without creating a new directive and using the ng-change to update the isInvalidName value whenever the input changes. By using a text input for the row, we can capture the event when the value changes and handle it accordingly.


angular
  .module("app", ["ui.grid", "ui.grid.edit", "ui.bootstrap"])
  .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: [{ name: "" }],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: "name",
          cellTemplate:
           '<div uib-popover="foo is not allowed" ' +
            '     popover-append-to-body="true" ' +
            '     popover-is-open="grid.appScope.isInvalidName" ' +
            '     popover-enable="grid.appScope.isInvalidName" ' +
            '     class="form-control">' +
            '<input type="text" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-change="grid.appScope.onInputChange(row, col, MODEL_COL_FIELD)" />'
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.onInputChange = function (row, col, newValue) {
      $scope.isInvalidName = newValue === "foo";
    };
  });
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>       

  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>isInvalidName = {{isInvalidName}}</label>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>



